# (Uniform) continuity of push-forward operator

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, uniform-continuity

I am wondering about extension of the the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574383/measurability-of-the-pushforward-operator-on-measures).

Namely, suppose $U$, $V$ are Polish spaces and $F:U→V$ is *uniformly* continuous. Does this mean that the push-forward operator $F_*: \mathcal{P}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(V)$ is also *uniformly* continuous when each $\mathcal{P}(.)$ is endowed with weak* topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Levy-Prohorov metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) on both $\mathcal P(U)$ and $\mathcal P(V)$, then $F_*$ is indeed uniformly continuous. The proof is a matter of chasing through the definitions, the key being to observe that 
$$
\{x\in U: d_U[x, F^{-1}(A)]<\delta\}\subset \{x\in U: d_V[F(x),A]<\epsilon\}.
$$
provided $A$ is a Borel subset sof $V$. Here, $\epsilon>0$, and $\delta$ is such that
$$
d_U[x,y]<\delta \Longrightarrow d_V[F(x),F(y)]<\epsilon,
$$
per the uniform continuity of $F$.

Comment: Thank you! For the special case that $U$ is compact, I realized also that one can use the fact that when $\mathcal{P}(U)$ has the weak* topology it is a compact space if $U$ is compact, and so a continuous operator on a compact space is uniformly continuous. But your solution is obviously better.

Comment: What is "uniformly continuous" supposed to mean, given that $U$ and $V$ have no uniform structures? A Polish space is a topological space *homeomorphic* to a separable, complete metric space, but notice that homeomorphisms do not preserve uniform (in particular metric) structures. So how is the question supposed to be understood?